# Displaying user's name in LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, loginview

The default website template when creating an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio shows the user's username when logged in in the LoginView. I would like to replace this with the user's first name. I have this stored in a database, so in the Site.master page I tried the following (in the page onload):

```
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    string id = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
       SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                using (SqlCommand con_get = new SqlCommand("SELECT firstname FROM x WHERE userId='" + id + "'", connection)) //Executes SQL command             
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open(); //Opens the database connection
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = con_get.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader != null)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Label label1 = (Label)sender;
                                    label1.Text = reader["x"].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close(); //Closes the database connection
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

This does not work at the moment. I also tried not using the sender and just tried to use label1.Text = reader["x"].ToString(); but that did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can make this work?

Also, is this the correct approach? Surely there is a more efficient way to load the first name and not reload this every time the user navigates to a different page (therefore reducing the # of queries against the database)?

Comment: It would probably help if you didn't silently discard all the possibly helpful error messages.  At least log them to a file or dump them out to the screen because that will be very useful to help debug the issue.

Comment: While debugging I have narrowed it down to an issue with setting the label value while it is inside the LoginView. If I use a label outside, it is fine. I am using this: Label new_label = (Label)HeadLoginView.Parent.FindControl("lbl");                                       string getPlayerName = reader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
new_label.Text = getPlayerName;
new_label.Visible = true;

Comment: Edit: Sorted it by doing the following: Label name_label = (Label)FindControl("HeadLoginView").FindControl("login_lbl"); to get to find the label, instead of Label name_label = HeadLoginView.FindControl("login_lbl");

Comment: I use a similar label in my web app, but I use a session object to hold the user name, then just call it whenever I need it.  I set the session object in the Global.asax.

Comment: Have you verified that GetUser() is actually returning something? I'm not sure what your datasource for that method is here. Since userprovider key is an object, I don't know if you're getting back a samaccount name or an integer, or what?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you end up running into is the fact that the label is located on the master page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      var welcomeLabel = Page.Master.FindControl("lblWelcome") as Label;
      SetName(welcomeLabel);
   }
}
```

Here's a handwritten login pattern:

```
protected void SetName(Label welcomeLabel)
{
    //this is the type of thing you'd probably wanna do in the Global.asax on session start
    if (Session["userName"] == null || !Login()) return; //session variable is empty and the login attempt failed, give up
    var usersName = Session["userName"].ToString();
    welcomeLabel.Text = usersName;
}
protected bool Login()
{
    const string query = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Password = @Password AND UserName = @UserName";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", password)); //or get this from a control or wherever
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName)); //or get this from a control or wherever
            conn.Open();
            var name = (string)comm.ExecuteScalar();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                Session["userName"] = name;
                return true;
            }
            //"Login information is wrong or user doesn't exist.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So all we're doing here is searching our database for a match between the username and password. The username should be unique, so kinda acts like your primary key, the AND filter just ensures that the passwords match the user name. Simple.

Generally speaking, i think you should be storing a bit more info about the user into the session just to make it worth your while. I generally create some form of a user object so that I can hit it whenever I need it, and then its all neatly accessible through the user object. I think that's what the Windows Membership classes are trying to help with, but I don't like to use them unless I doing windows authentication. But that's just preference.